# HornetQ Role based security implementation

Tags: jboss, hornetq, jbossfuse, jboss-eap-6

Iam trying to secure hornet Q using role based security implementation.
    iam using FSW 6.0 which uses Jboss EAP 6.1.

Standalone xml configuration.

```
<security-settings>
                    <security-setting match="#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    </security-setting>
                    <security-setting match="Pricing.Eu.In.#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="pricing"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="pricing"/>
                    </security-setting>
                </security-settings>

I have created a new user using add-user.bat  Application Realm and assigned role to it.
```

application-roles.Properties

```
#
# Properties declaration of users roles for the realm 'ApplicationRealm'.
#
# This includes the following protocols: remote ejb, remote jndi, web, remote jms
#
# Users can be added to this properties file at any time, updates after the server has started
# will be automatically detected.
#
# The format of this file is as follows: -
# username=role1,role2,role3
#
# A utility script is provided which can be executed from the bin folder to add the users: -
# - Linux
#  bin/add-user.sh
#
# - Windows
#  bin\add-user.bat
#
# The following illustrates how an admin user could be defined.
#
#admin=PowerUser,BillingAdmin,
#guest=guest
fswAdmin=overlorduser,admin.sramp,dev,qa,stage,prod,manager,arch,ba
dtgovworkflows=overlorduser,admin.sramp
guest=guest
cubehpr=pricing
```

When i try to send messages to the Pricing.Eu.In.Deferred jms Queue using client application iam getting below error.
    Am i missing anything?

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: HQ119032: User: cubehpr doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}
      at org.hornetq.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:388)
      at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.sendRegularMessage(ClientProducerImpl.java:318)
      at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.doSend(ClientProducerImpl.java:288)
      at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl.send(ClientProducerImpl.java:140)
      at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.doSend(HornetQMessageProducer.java:438)
      at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQMessageProducer.send(HornetQMessageProducer.java:194)
      at com.agcs.bih.api.pricing.eu.dispatcher.HornetQClient.main(HornetQClient.java:63)
    Caused by: HornetQException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=HQ119032: User: cubehpr doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}]
      ... 7 more

can you please help me.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
                <security-settings>
                    <security-setting match="jms.queue.Pricing.Eu.In.#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="pricing"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="pricing"/>
                    </security-setting>
                    <security-setting match="#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    </security-setting>
                </security-settings>
```